# Polynomial Relationship (Bounded by a Constant)

Tags: real-analysis

I am working on an example step in a differential equations textbook and cannot justify a property that is introduced for a nth degree polynomial.

$\left| p_{{n}} \left( x \right)  \right|$  ≤ 
$C_{{n}} \left(  \left| x \right|  \right) ^{n}$, for  $1\leq  \left| x \right|$ and constant $C_{{n}}$.

What is the best way to show the above relationship? 
I know that $p_{{n}} \left( x \right) =\sum _{k=0}^{n}a_{{k}}{x}^{k}$, for

$p_{{n}} \left( x \right)$ = $a_{{0}}+a_{{1}}x+...+a_{{n}}{x}^{n}$, for non-zero $a_{{n}}$.

This reminds me of a norm property to show that the x-components are bounded above by a constant C, but I cannot remember where I have seen this relationship / transformation before. I would appreciate any guidance on this.

Answer (score 1):

Set $C_n = \sum _{k=0}^n \lvert a_k\rvert =
\lvert a_0\rvert + \lvert a_1\rvert + \cdots + \lvert a_n\rvert$.
Since $\lvert a_k x^k\rvert \leq \lvert a_k\rvert(\lvert x\rvert)^n$ for all $0\leq k\leq n$
when $\lvert x\rvert \geq 1$, the conclusion follows.